# how to Iterate multimap values in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, foreach, multimap

How do I iterate or receive the value from a multimap? I have one key and that is associated with some array value. I want the first key, then all values, then second key other values, but I don't know how to iterate over multimap.

Here is my code:

Here is my servlet where I am calling my business logic class method

```
    public class Emp_Mapping extends HttpServlet
    {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
    Employee emp1 = (Employee)session.getAttribute("emp1");
    session.setAttribute("emp1",emp1);    
    EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();   
    List<Employee> detail2 = eb.emp_map_detail1(emp1);//here i am calling
         System.out.println(detail2);       
        request.setAttribute("detail2",detail2);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/EmployeeMapping.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }}
```

Here is my method which of Employee class which I have kept as business logic class where all request coming after servlet to specific method by method call.
Here it's working fine and it is holding the required value as I want:

```
      public List<Employee> emp_map_detail1(Employee emp1) {
      Connection con = null;
      Statement stmt2,stmt3,stmt4 = null;  
      ResultSet rs2 =null;
      ResultSet rs3 =null;
      ResultSet rs4 =null;
      int e1=0, e2=0,e3=0,e4=0;
      String n2=null,n1=null,n4=null;
      List<Employee> detail2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
      Multimap<String, String> multimap1 = ArrayListMultimap.create();
      Multimap<String, String> multimap2 = ArrayListMultimap.create();  

      List<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();          
      try{
      con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
      stmt2 = con.createStatement();
      String Query12 = "select empId, empName from empinfo where access_type='manager'";
      System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query12);
      rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(Query12);
      while(rs2.next())
      {
      e1 =Integer.parseInt(rs2.getString("empId"));
      n1 = rs2.getString("empName");
      myList2.add(n1);        
      stmt3 = con.createStatement();
      String Query13 = "select empId, empName from empinfo where empId in 
      (select distinct   employee_teamleader from employeegroup 
      where employee_manager='"+e1+"')  and access_type ='teamleader' ";
      System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query13);
      rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery(Query13);
      while(rs3.next())
      {
      e3 =Integer.parseInt(rs3.getString("empId"));
      n2 = rs3.getString("empName");    
       multimap1.put(n1,n2);
          stmt4 = con.createStatement();
       String Query14 = "select empId, empName from empinfo where
       empId in (select distinct employee_name from employeegroup 
       where employee_teamleader='"+e3+"') and access_type ='employee'";
       System.out.println("Query1 is" +Query14);
       rs4 = stmt4.executeQuery(Query14);
       while(rs4.next())
      {
       e4 =Integer.parseInt(rs4.getString("empId"));
       n4 =rs4.getString("empName");
       multimap2.put(n2,n4);
       System.out.println("multimap1" +multimap1);
        System.out.println("multimap2" +multimap2);
       }}}
        emp1.setEmpname2(multimap2);
        emp1.setManname1(myList2);
        emp1.setTlname2(multimap1);
       detail2.add(emp1);
       emp1.setValid(true);
      }  
      catch (SQLException  ex) {

      } finally {
          try {
              if (stmt4 != null) {
                  stmt4.close();
              }
              if (con != null) {
                  con.close();
              }
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(EmployeeBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
      }
    return detail2;
    }
```

Here is employee bean class in which I have all associated methods to employee. Here I have provided only the required setter and getter method with the variable:

```
      public class Employee 
      {
      private Multimap<String, String> tlname2;

    public Multimap<String, String> getTlname2() {
    return tlname2;
     }
    public void setTlname2(Multimap<String, String> tlname2) {
    this.tlname2 = tlname2;
     }
     }
```

Here in jsp how to print. I don't know it's not getting iterate in this way:

```
<c:forEach var="temp" items="${emp1.tlname2}">
 ${temp}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try jsp below:

```
<c:forEach var="myMap" items="${emp1.tlnameMap}">
  <c:out value=" key is ${myMap.key}" />
  <c:forEach var="mapValue" items="${myMap.value}" varStatus="count">
        <c:out value=" value ${count.index} is ${mapValue}" />
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach
```

And create a new method which will return map view of multiMap as below:

```
public Map<String, Collection<String>> getTlnameMap() {
    return tlname2.asMap();
}
```

Comment: no if i use detail2 then also not working sir please check it properly why i am using tlname2 instead of detail2 because i have different values u see it and please try to help me and its not normal one its multimap thats why giving problem

Comment: where have you defined tlname2? Please paste only relevant code and not whole project code.

Comment: is it guava multimap or commons collections? You should clarify before asking any questions.

Comment: Why dont you use Map<String, String> instead of MultiMap<String, String>? Its not what multimap is meant for?

Comment: and my array values are like this  {Sampath=[Thamil, A.K.karan], Kanan =[john]} and so this i have to display

Comment: i want to save duplicate value or in same key i want to store multi values like john=[Saurabh, chunky Pandey, Kiran, Karuna]

Comment: the solution u have provided in this <c:forEach var="myMap" items="${emp1.tlnameMap}"> where this tlnameMap variable? because i was using emp1.tlname2 so can you explain me...

Comment: yea i saw that in that it is public Map<String, Collection<String>> getTlnameMap() so it is Tlname not tlname so i am confused

Comment: and one more error it is showing like this ... /EmployeeMapping.jsp (line: 286, column: 66) equal symbol expected so i think some error is there may be in this line <c:out value=" value ${count.index} is ${mapValue}" />

Comment: when i removed this varStatus="count"  it is coming

Comment: Ahh.. i missed an ending quote and hence error. If you think this has helped, then close this question by accepting the answer so it could be used by others in future.

Comment: yea i will but i have to ask something more in this... i will ask you by tomorrow then i will hit it..

Comment: You don't have to continue on this.. instead ask a new question tomorrow.

Comment: previously i was saving value like this {Sampath=[Thamil, A.K.karan], Kanan =[john]} it is fine so can i hold value like this  {Sampath={Thamil=[xi,x2,x3], x=[A.K.karan,zr,px]}, bala={krishna rao=[y1,y2,y3], U=[z1,z2,z3]}}  using multimap just tell me structure how can i define so i can proceed... plz

Comment: This is follow up question hence i would advice you to open a new question and close this one.

Comment: yea sir i have done and sorry for delay and i will ask that in some time